# Limit the gas consumption in the loops

Tags: solidity, transactions, gas, evm

Here's the situation. The contract has a function that iterates through the struct array, which can also contain arrays. That is, the function will contain a loop within a loop. I understand that if this is not limited in any way and the array contains many elements, then the function may not complete due to the gas limit. I have several ways to solve this problem.

1. Abandon the loops altogether. (most likely it will not be possible to do this)
2. Abandon the loops in the contract and call the function in the loop through the backend.
3. Limit the loop within the contract to n iterations.

Questions.
Which of these solutions is more correct?
Are there any examples of other solutions, for example, in known protocols?
Do I understand correctly that the second solution will be more expensive than the first because EVM charges a minimum fee of 21k gas?

Comment: if your loop takes more than 5 seconds, `Geth` will abort your call to the contract and return an error

Comment: the solution is not to use loops

Comment: if you can, you can make other people pay for your loops. some token contracts will take the remaining gas after finalizing a method and use that to move data around the contract. but that is still consumption though.